# Use Python (PyAutoGUI) Automation in Windows Server

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui, windows-server, rpa

I'm using Python 3.9 and PyAutoGUI to automate some processes in a program. This automation must run on a Windows Server

I'm using object recognition, with, buttons, text boxes, mouse and keyboard functions.
This automation must run in the Windows Task Scheduler, with elevated privileges and only when the user is logged in (to be able to send commands and recognize objects on the screen).

But with the whole environment set up correctly, and manually running the automation, when it's run by the task scheduler, it doesn't complete the task.

I tried to run the automation through the task scheduler, but without success. When I run it manually and with the server open, it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to troubleshoot/add more info
when running thru the task scheduler, does it run at all?
if it does run(but not properly), then it's likely an issue with permissions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).